# How to discard equal value in query?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm using `CodeIgniter` for manage my web-application, actually I've write this query:

```
$query = $this->db
          ->select('GroupID')
          ->from('ea_appointments')
          ->where('id_users_provider', $record_id)
          ->get()->result_array();
```

the result returned is this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["GroupID"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["GroupID"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(1) { ["GroupID"]=> string(1) "2" } }
```

How you can see I've this `GroupID` valorization:

> 1 - 1 - 2

I need to discard the equal values and get only:

> 1 -  2

How I can achieve this in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add group by in your query

```
$this->db->select('GroupID')
          ->group_by('GroupID')
          ->from('ea_appointments')
          ->where('id_users_provider', $record_id)
          ->get()->result_array();
```

Or you can use distinct in your query

```
$this->db->distinct()
              ->select('GroupID')
              ->from('ea_appointments')
              ->where('id_users_provider', $record_id)
              ->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be adding distinct worked

```
$this->db->select('DISTINCT GroupID')
      ->from('ea_appointments')
      ->where('id_users_provider', $record_id)
      ->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$this->db->distinct();
```